# how to make logo, navbar and search bar all in one row in bootstrap and in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, navbar, react-bootstrap

im trying to put the logo in the same line with search bar and navbar using bootstrap in Reactjs but i couldnt

here is my code

```
import { Navbar, Nav, form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import React from 'react';
import './Navbar.css'

export function NavbarComponent() {
    return (
        <>
            <Navbar class="p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-white" >
                <Navbar.Brand href="#home">
                    <img className="logo"
                        src="http://www.yatak.com/content/assets/default/img/logo.png"
                        width="20%"
                        height="10%"
                        alt="logo" />
                    <Navbar class="p-3 bg-light text-dark">
                        <form class="form-inline mx-auto">
                            <input class="form-control mx-auto" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                        </form>
                        <Nav className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                            <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="#products">Products</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="#aboutus">About Us</Nav.Link>
                            <Nav.Link href="#contactus">Contact Us</Nav.Link>
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar>
                </Navbar.Brand>
            </Navbar>
        </>
    );
}
export default NavbarComponent;
```

any help would be highly apperciated!

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your issue

```
import { Navbar, Nav, Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

function NavBarComponent() {
    return (
        <Navbar class="p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-white" bg="light" expand="lg">
            <Navbar.Brand href="#home">
                <img className="logo"
                    src="http://www.acaryatak.com/content/assets/default/img/logo.png"
                    width="100px"
                    height="10%"
                    alt="Acar Yatak logo" />
            </Navbar.Brand>

            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />

            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="ml-auto">
                    <Form inline>
                        <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
                        <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
                    </Form>

                    <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="#products">Products</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="#aboutus">About Us</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="#contactus">Contact Us</Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    );
}

export default NavBarComponent;
```